# Custom message in Tablewizard

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

How do I show a custom message in the table wizard when table has no data. I am working with Telerik Reports Q1 2011.

Answer (score 0):

There is NoDataMessage property of table item. You can add epression and the message will be displayed. Also, you can give styling to NoDataMessage. Or go to itemdatabound event of table item and then set the value for no data message.

```
private void table1_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Take the Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DataItem instance
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Table tbl = Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DataItem)sender;

    //Check if data is retrieved by graph or not.
    if (table1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
          //If no data retrieved, then set the NoDataMessage property.
          tbl.NoDataMessage = "No Data Found";
    }
}
```

Link: 
http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-structure-dataitem-set-no-data-message.html